# Coded UI Test Recorder Often Hangs When Trying to Generate Code

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I often find that after I have finished recording my actions using the Coded UI Test Recorder and I click "Generate Code", the recorder hangs on the "Please Wait" progress bar and never generates the code (see image link).

[Please Wait progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI05z.png)

I do not perform a large number of actions and I perform them slowly to allow each action to be acknowledged before performing the next.

I am recording actions performed on a WinForms application which contains Infragistics components.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 5.

My laptop spec: 2.9GHz Intel Core i7 processor with 8GB of RAM running Windows 7 Professional.

There is plenty of memory and disk space available whilst recording.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve this issue?

Is there any logging anywhere that I can look at that might indicate what the problem is?

The inspector does not hang and is able to locate any control. This problem is only with the recorder.

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: Does it hang when recording a window which does not contain the infragistics stuff?  Also, does the inspector hang or is it able to find elements?  Placing your mouse over the component and pressing Ctrl + Shift + Alt + i    will initiate the inspector.  Lastly, consider not using the record and play at all.  See codeduiexamples.com for examples of how to easily write your own scripts.

Comment: The inspector does not hang and is able to locate any control. Thanks for that URL, I will take a look.